# How can I make an alliance member hate me and declare war on me?

Tags: freeciv

When playing against the AI, I sometimes find myself in a multinational alliance that includes a nation I dislike. I have a peace treaty with this nation. I would like that nation to declare war on me so that I can attack them without breaking my existing alliances. How can I do this in Freeciv? I have tried to bribe their units, and pillage their roads, mines, and irrigation.